# empty tag {% empty %} in django template doesn't work when "if" condition is nested inside for loop

Tags: django

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% if title in entry %}
            <li><a href="/{{ entry }}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
        <li>Sorry! No result matches your search.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is my html template.
Want to create a list where the list items have to meet certain condition, so I nested if condition inside for loop. The list works, but empty tag doesn't.
When the list is empty, it doesn't show anything.
How can I make it work?

Comment: The `if` tag should not have anything to do with the `for..empty` loop. Are you sure your `entries` list is empty? Does it work when you delete the `if` block?

Comment: It works when if block is removed. Whether "for loop" is empty depends on if block, if there is no item match if statement, it will be empty. if there is one or some items satisfy if statement it will not be empty. Or.., is this kind of syntax valid?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have misunderstood the `{% empty %}` tag. It only works if `entries` is empty or not found. It doesn't matter if any HTML is generated inside the `for` loop, so it is independent of your `if` clause.

What you can do is to filter `entries` in your view code to only return entries with `title` in them.